# How to create Kafka topic using Segmentio's kafka-go?

Tags: go, kafka-topic, segment-io

Can I get an example of creating a topic using segmentio's kafka-go?

I have tried creating a topic as below:

```
c, _ := kafka.Dial("tcp", "host:port")
kt := kafka.TopicConfig{Topic: "sometopic", NumPartitions: 1, ReplicationFactor: 1}
e := c.CreateTopics(kt)
```

But this will work only if the given **host:port** is Kafka Leader. If the **host:port** is not Kafka Leader, then I will be getting this error:

> Not Controller: this is not the correct controller for this cluster*

What is the right way of passing clusters address for creating a topic?

Kafka Segmentio: [github.com/segmentio/kafka-go](http://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go)

Comment: `kafka.DialLeader(context.Background(), "tcp", "host:port", topic, partition)` ?

Comment: @dmkvl However, you cannot dial a leader for a topic which doesn't exist yet?

Comment: there are 3 different ways to create topics [here](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go/blob/main/createtopics_test.go).

Answer (score 2):

Like shmsr said - you need to get the Leader connection to create topics. You can do that in the following way:

```
conn, err := kafka.Dial("tcp", "host:port")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
defer conn.Close()

controller, err := conn.Controller()
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
controllerConn, err := kafka.Dial("tcp", net.JoinHostPort(controller.Host, strconv.Itoa(controller.Port)))
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
defer controllerConn.Close()

topicConfigs := []kafka.TopicConfig{{Topic: "sometopic", NumPartitions: 1, ReplicationFactor: 1}}

err = controllerConn.CreateTopics(topicConfigs...)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```golang
func (c *Conn) Controller() (broker Broker, err error)
// Controller requests kafka for the current controller and returns its URL
```

When you open the connection in your code using Dial, you are randomly picking one of the brokers in the cluster. Hence, you may/ may not end up on the actual Kafka controller. A simple lookup for the controller and opening a new connection should be helpful.

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/segmentio/kafka-go?tab=doc#Conn.Controller